# Angular TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, exception, npm

I had a working project until I attempted to install ExcelJs (`npm install --save exceljs`).

After that I began receiving various errors such as  `Cannot read property ‘Minus’ of undefined` and `Cannot find module 'postcss-value-something'` which were solved by `npm i`ing whatever the missing parts were.

After this however, I now receive `TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined`.

Having ran into these issues I removed the excelJs in the hopes some normality would return however, no such luck.

The full error is as follows:

```
    at setPrototypeOf (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__extends (F:\Honeycomb\Honey\Varroa\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:68:9)
    at F:\Honeycomb\Honey\Varroa\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:118:17
    at F:\Honeycomb\Honey\Varroa\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:325:6
    at F:\Honeycomb\Honey\Varroa\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:3:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Honeycomb\Honey\Varroa\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\template.js:9:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at F:\Honeycomb\Honey\Varroa\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\transform.js:21:22
    at F:\Honeycomb\Honey\Varroa\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\transform.js:10:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Honeycomb\Honey\Varroa\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\ngtsc\indexer\src\transform.js:16:3)
```

The contents of my package.json are as follows:

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.1.0",
    "@agm/js-marker-clusterer": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.6",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "^8.2.14",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/angular": "^1.6.47",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.28.16",
    "angular2-text-mask": "8.0.4",
    "angular2-toaster": "^8.0.0",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.2",
    "brace": "0.11.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "codemirror": "5.33.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "core-js": "2.5.3",
    "dragula": "3.7.2",
    "file-saver": "^1.3.8",
    "flag-icon-css": "2.9.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "highcharts": "7.0.2",
    "highcharts-angular": "2.4.0",
    "highcharts-boost": "^0.1.7",
    "html2canvas": "^1.0.0-alpha.12",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "js-marker-clusterer": "^1.0.0",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "moment": "^2.20.1",
    "ng-mat-select-infinite-scroll": "^2.0.0",
    "ng-select": "^1.0.2",
    "ng2-ace-editor": "^0.3.9",
    "ng2-charts": "1.6.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^3.0.0-beta.2",
    "ng2-dragula": "1.5.0",
    "ng2-file-upload": "1.2.1",
    "ng2-select": "^2.0.0",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "2.0.0-rc.0",
    "ngx-loading": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-quill": "^8.1.8",
    "normalize.css": "^7.0.0",
    "oidc-client": "^1.5.1",
    "postcss-value-parser": "^4.1.0",
    "primeicons": "4.0.0",
    "primeng": "9.1.0",
    "raven-js": "^3.26.2",
    "rxjs": "6.2.1",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.1",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "spinkit": "1.2.5",
    "ts-helpers": "1.1.2",
    "ts-overlapping-marker-spiderfier": "^1.0.2",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "xlsx": "0.13.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.24",
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.28",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.0.2",
    "@angular/language-service": "^10.0.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.6.1",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.3",
    "@types/file-saver": "0.0.1",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.37.7",
    "@types/highcharts": "5.0.36",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.11",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.110",
    "@types/luxon": "^1.11.1",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.19",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^5.0.2",
    "jasminewd2": "^2.2.0",
    "karma": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "1.3.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^3.3.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.4",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "rxjs-tslint": "^0.1.8",
    "ts-node": "4.1.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.2",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.1.0"
  }
```

Everywhere I have read so far suggests that the cli / compiler cli is at fault but I was under the impression that the `^` means it updates as necessary, I have also tried to remove the `^` incase the version had gone beyond my project's supported Angular version.

`ng v` returns the following:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.28
Node: 10.16.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.0.0
... animations, common, compiler, core, forms, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.28
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.28
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.28
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.28
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.28
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.28
@angular/cdk                      7.3.7
@angular/cli                      8.3.28
@angular/compiler-cli             10.0.2
@angular/http                     7.2.16
@angular/language-service         10.0.2
@angular/material                 7.3.7
@angular/upgrade                  8.2.14
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.28
@schematics/angular               8.3.28
@schematics/update                0.803.28
rxjs                              6.2.1
typescript                        3.9.6
webpack                           4.43.0
```

I suspect it is still to do with the compiler/cli version or even typescript, as I have seen written elsewhere, however there does not appear to be any guide as to which versions should be used with what.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your angular package versions are so out of sync! Somehow your compiler-cli is at 10.0.2, but your http is at 7.2.16. How did that happen? Anyways, the best way to upgrade your angular is using `ng update @angular/cli`, `ng update @angular/core` and `ng update @angular/material`.

This will update it to version 10, and hopefully does the appropriate migrations. Whatever starts with @angular should always have the same major version. In your case you are mixing v7 with v8 and v10. Throw in v9 and you have a quartet.

If the updating doesn't work using the cli, you might be better of using these steps:

- save your source code , which is under `src`, and any other files you might deem worth saving, like `package.json` to check any non angular packages you are using.
- remove the entire project folder
- upgrade your global `@angular/cli` by using `ng -g i @angular/cli@latest`
- create a new project using `ng new xxx`
- copy your src to the newly created project, but skip the `main.ts`, `polyfills.ts` and the `tsconfig` files, because there have been major changes with the latest angular cli version
- optional: update those non copied files with any custom changes you might have done, like the `package.json`

From there on, always use `ng update` to upgrade any angular module, because this also includes the necessary code migrations.

As a side note, the `^` will just update the minor version of your installed package if you do `npm update`. Read more [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I will get started on attempting these updates. The project has been neglected and the bare minimum done for maintenance in terms of any requested feature changes over the years. There is a good chance that the mismatch of versions came from avoiding errors from old modules/packages that are in use.

Comment: IIRC we use agm which is not compatible with later versions of angular.

Comment: @Divine in that case you should revert to the compatible angular version, and never update :) Although the latest [agm version](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) does support later angular versions

Comment: is it likely that I would need to downgrade the cli? to an 8.X to match the other versions then?